# How does sort command work in this specific case?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

So I have a text file named sortingnames.txt and it looks like this under the cat command.

```
A. Thaliana
E. Coli
H. sapiens
S. cerevisiae
A thaliana
E Coli
H sapiens
S cerevisiae
A. Thaliana (plant)
E. Coli (Bacteria)
H. Sapiens (Human)
S. Cerevisiae (Yeast)
203 characters?
A. Thaliana Plant
```

Then I run sort command $sort -k 3.2 sortingnames.txt.
The result pops up like this.

```
203 characters
A thaliana
A. Thaliana
E Coli
E. Coli
H sapiens
H. sapiens
S cerevisiae
S. cerevisiae
E. Coli (Bacteria)
H. Sapiens (Human)
A. Thaliana (plant)
A. Thaliana Plant
S. Cerevisiae (Yeast)
```

The ordering of the last 5 lines does not make sense to me. Assuming sort does not take punctuations like ( into account, the 3rd character of E. Coli (Bacteria) is c and the next line with (Human) is m. The 3rd character of the plant lines are a and for yeast line is a.

And yet bash returns this. Can someone explain why?

Comment: What's your locale? What does `locale` output?

Comment: `-k 3.2` means "the third field, starting from character 2". It does not select the third character of anything.

Comment: Locale outputs LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: @thatotherguy No it does not, but it still does not explain why the second-to-last line is sorted the way it is in relation to the one above it ("plant" before "lant").

Comment: Use `--debug` on the `sort` command to see what keys it is using.

Comment: @Kusalananda A field is anything after a nonblank-to-blank transition, so I includes the space. It doesn't compare `plant` and `lant`, but `plant` and `(plant`

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be an issue with the collation sequence related to `en_US.UTF-8`.  In this case the left paren - `(` - is effectively ignored leaving the last 5 lines looking like:

```
E. Coli Bacteria)
H. Sapiens Human)
A. Thaliana plant)
A. Thaliana Plant
S. Cerevisiae Yeast)
```

So when you apply the `-k3.2` ... keeping in mind the leading white space **is** included in the counting ... you're left with the following sort results:

```
' Bacteria)'
' Human)'
' plant)'
' Plant'
' Yeast)'
```

And when you consider a case-insensitive sort order, with lower-case having precedence over upper-case ... the results are correct ... for `en_US.UTF-8`.

Try changing your `LANG` variable, eg, `unset LANG`. In my SLES environment all the `LC_*` variables switch to "POSIX", and when I run the sort again and I find the left paren is now considered as part of the sort string so when applying `-k3.2` I get:

```
' (Bacteria)
' (Human)
' (Yeast)
' (plant)
' Plant
```

... but in this case the left paren has precedence over letters, and we see case-sensitive ordering with upper-case having precedence over lower-case ... for `LANG=` (and the various `LC_*` variables = "POSIX")

Comment: Can you tell me if there is a book or a website I can learn more about this stuff? Thanks!